# Fedora 20 freezes on reboot and poweroff

Tags: fedora, reboot

This freeze happens when I try to `reboot`, `shutdown -r now`, `poweroff`, `shutdown -h now` etc. One time it freezes on my desktop image, and the other time it freezes on the fedora logo. I am dual booting Fedora 20 with Windows 8, which shouldn't matter.

Comment: Does the system freezewhen in Windows?

Comment: @slm no, this only occurs when rebooting and powering off in fedora.

Comment: Sounds like a driver/device combo is not strictly compatible and the system is hanging on the unloading of hte drivers for this hardware component. Does `dmesg` show anything about this? Also what does `journalctl` show anything about it when you bring the system back up for the timeframe where you attempted to do a shutdown?

Comment: Ctrl-Function Key to escape Desktop X session while using Fedora, starting a terminal. Login as root. Kill the X session process. Try the reboot command to see if still hangs or if any useful messages displayed.